# Worst Case Time Complexity of Depth First Search

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I know the answer to this particular question is O(V + E) and for a Graph like a tree, it makes sense because each Vertex is being explored once only.

However let's say there is a cycle in the graph.

For example, let's take up an undirected graph with four vertices A-B-C-D.
A is connected to both B and C, and Both B and C are connected to D. So there are four edges in total. A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D and vice versa.

Let's do DFS(A).

It will explore B first and B's neighbor D and D's neighbor C. After that C will not have any edges so it will come back to D and B and then A.

Then A will traverse its second edge and try to explore C and since it is already explored it will not do anything and DFS will end.

But over here Vertex "C" has been traversed twice, not once. Clearly worst case time complexity can be directly proportional to V.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a D->C in your graph so it should start back tracking from D.
So the traversal should be A->B->D, A->C.

Comment: @Ayos it is a undirected graph  so since C->D is there D->C is also there, sorry for the incorrect representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not maintain a **`visited` set**, that you use to **avoid revisitting already visited nodes**, DFS is not `O(V+E)`. In fact, it is not complete algorithm - thus it might not even find a path if there is a one, because it will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Note that for infinite graphs, if you are looking for a path from `s` to `t`, even with maintaining a visited set, it is not guaranteed to complete, since you might get stuck in an infinite branch.

If you are interested in keeping DFS's advantage of efficient space consumption, while still being complete - you might use [iterative deepening DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), but it will not trivially solve the problem if you are looking to discover the whole graph, and not a path to a specific node.

**EDIT**: DFS pseudo code with `visited` set.

```
DFS(v,visited):
  for each u such that (v,u) is an edge:
       if (u is not in visited):
            visited.add(u)
            DFS(u,visited)
```

It is easy to see that you invoke the recursion on a vertex if and only if it is not yet visited, thus the answer is indeed linear in the number of vertices and edges.

Comment: I am using visited set that is the reason why BFS retreated back from C in the graph because both of its neighbors (A,D) are already explored/visited. But it will check for this vertex C  again when out program returns to A the starting node but since it is already visited it will be ignored and loop will end.. so C is visited twice IMO Please Draw this graph if possible to be on the same wave length

Comment: @Batman: I added a pseudo code with a DFS that maintains a `visited` set and visits each vertex at most once, I hope it makes things clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit each vertex and edge of the graph a constant number of times and still be O(V+E).  An alternative way of looking at it is that the cost is charged to the edge, not to the vertex.

Comment: Can you be more specific or can you tell it to me in the context of the graph I sort of showed in the question (A,B,C,D)